# How to display content type name on related image?

Tags: views, theming

I have create one content type[article] with two by default field i.e. title and body.
In body summary part we have contain one image on left side and description on right side.

I want display the content type name on that image which is show in summary part.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In FIELDS add Content Type as a field and check mark exclude from display.

2) Make sure Content Type is ABOVE Body field, other wise you will not get Content Type token as a replacement pattern.

3) Click on your Body field and in REWRITE RESULTS, checkmark override output of this field.

Then use the replacement patterns.

[image]

The above is for Drupal 8, in Drupal 7 it would be `[type_1] [body__summary]`

You can add html if you need ex: `<div class="type">[type_1]</div> [body__summary]`

> **Bonus:** You could remove the image from Summary Part and instead add an image field to your content type. Then add your image as a
>   field to your view. Then when you REWRITE RESULTS you can add the image there
>   `[type_1][field_image][body__summary]`

---

**PS:** Next time tell us which Drupal version you are using!